# How to copy row and place another page into table in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, row

I can not find google, how to work only with the row in the table. I did some code, but I do not know how to do it, selecting only one row data.

**index.php**

```
<?=Html::submitButton('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-info',]);?>

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],

        'id',
        'name',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

in **MasaController.php**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new CasaSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}

public function actionMasa(){
    $action=Yii::$app->request->post('action');
    $selection=(array)Yii::$app->request->post('selection');//typecasting
    foreach($selection as $id){
     $model = Post::findOne((int)$id);//make a typecasting
     //do your stuff
     $model->save();
     // or delete
   }
 }
```

I want to see this page masa.php

[image]

Help me please

Comment: Thx, I do not know English well

Comment: you want to get redirected to index page again? Unclear what you are asking

Comment: I do not want to redirect the page, I want to transfer the data to a new page

Comment: you want to display your selection in another page? then get selection, find selected records and render as a new page. I guess, you want to save data before this.

Comment: If you want to see masa.php you have to create the relative view and render it

Answer (score 1):

Is index.php in Masa directory?

just use:

```
echo Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('index',[your params]);
```

Comment: Thx, for help, I want select row, and to place new page

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say when you click on "Masa Row" go to new page?

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
'columns' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => '{view} {update} {delete} {myButton}',
        'buttons' => [
            'myButton' => function($url, $model, $key) {
                return Html::a(..);
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

when you will click on the mybutton you will get redirected to url that you will add to anchor tag